# Method local variable being modified inside a Parallel.For. How thread safe is this?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I have this code snippet:

```
int totalData = result.Data.Count;
int count = 0;
Parallel.ForEach(result.Data, data =>
{
    try
    {
        EventRange importedEntity = ImportEntity(auxResult.EntityName, data);
        count++;
        EntityImported(importedEntity, count, totalData);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        exceptions.Enqueue(e);
    }
});
```

EntityImported is an event that should say how many entities have been processed already, and how much entities I should process. My worries lie around the thread safety of incrementing count inside the lambda, and what steps you would recommend towards ensuring that the event is always fired with the correct value of the count variable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not at all thread-safe at the moment.

You can use `Interlocked.Increment(ref count)` instead, but it's *generally* better to have a "local" value for each thread, and sum them at the end. That way you don't need to have any sort of cross-thread data flow, other than allocating the items to be processed.

There's an overload of [`Parallel.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991486%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) designed for just this purpose - look at the example near the bottom of the documentation, as it's doing something *very* similar to your code. (It maintains a local count, and then sums the counts at the end.) Unfortunately that doesn't help in your particular case due to the way you need to raise an event on each iteration - but *usually* that's a better approach.

In this case, you should use the result of `Interlocked.Increment` in your event raising code:

```
Parallel.ForEach(result.Data, data =>
{
    try
    {
        EventRange importedEntity = ImportEntity(auxResult.EntityName, data);
        int newCount = Interlocked.Increment(ref count);
        EntityImported(importedEntity, newCount, totalData);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        exceptions.Enqueue(e);
    }
});
```

That way there will be exactly one event raised for each count (so one with 0, one with 1, one with 2 etc).

Comment: Thanks Jon, though I'm not sure I understand how that overload could help me. If I understand correctly, it allows me to pass to the lambda a certain value, sum it on a normal manner, and then do a final operation with it in order to minimize the amount of necessary interlocked operations.
It would serve me if I needed to do an operation with the total amount of processed entities. My problem, however, is that I need to raise an event with the current amount of processed entities at the moment each one is processed. Am I misunderstanding something or that overload wouldn't serve me well?

Comment: @Uri: Ah, I'd missed that. In that case just fall back to using Interlocked.Increment.

Comment: @Uri: You still have the issue that between the time of the Interlocked.Increment and the call to EntityImported, count may have changed. The optimizer may optimize out going back to memory for that value, but it may not. It may not be as fast, but you may want to create a local variable inside the lambda, lock before incrementing count, then copy count local. eg => importedEntity = blah(); int internalcount; lock(lock_object){ interlocked.inc(count); internalcount=count;} EntityImported(count,importedEntity);

Comment: @Bengie: The race is a good point, but there's no need to use locking. Just use the return value of `Interlocked.Increment` - see my edited answer for sample code.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I just learned something new, Interlocked.Increment returns the value. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you both, I didn't think at all about that possibility and worse than all, I did try to find race conditions. Can't believe I missed that one.